# 'Invalid character constant' Java

Tags: java

```
package meraba;

public class sinif1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String emre = 'Emre';

        System.out.println(emre);

    }

}
```

Where is the problem? I'm new to java,thanks

Answer (score 3):

Strings in Java are in double quotations `""`, single quotations `''` are for characters only.